# Javascript: creating dynamic variables and object names. / html5 localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, variables, loops

I'm working on a form that is saved by HTML5 local storage.

When pressing save:

```
function saveAll(){
  var field1 = document.getElementById('field1').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field1',field1);
  var field2 = document.getElementById('field2').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field2',field2);
  var field3 = document.getElementById('field3').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field3',field3);
  var field4 = document.getElementById('field4').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field4',field4);
  var field5 = document.getElementById('field5').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field5',field5);
  var field6 = document.getElementById('field6').value;
  localStorage.setItem('con_field6',field6);
}
```

And when loading the page (fills out the forms):

```
function ShowAll() {
  var field1 = localStorage.getItem('con_field1');
  document.conditioning.field1.value = field1;
  var field2 = localStorage.getItem('con_field2');
  document.conditioning.field2.value = field2;
  var field3 = localStorage.getItem('con_field3');
  document.conditioning.field3.value = field3;
  var field4 = localStorage.getItem('con_field4');
  document.conditioning.field4.value = field4;
  var field5 = localStorage.getItem('con_field5');
  document.conditioning.field5.value = field5;
  var field6 = localStorage.getItem('con_field6');
  document.conditioning.field6.value = field6;
}
```

This all works fine, but I want to re-write this in a more fancy and efficient way. I was thinking of something like this:

```
function ShowAll() {
  var field = [];
  for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    field[i] = localStorage.getItem(window['con_field' + i]);
    document.purpose.field[i].value = window['con_field' + i]
  }
}
```

But the browser is not enjoying this. Basically I need to create a loop that automatically changes the "field" name in to 'field1, field2, field3' etc. The window thing is working, but I'm just using it wrong.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
function showAll(t1,c1,d1)  {
    var field1 = localStorage.getItem('con_field1');
    console.log(field1)
    var field2 = localStorage.getItem('con_field2');
    var field3 = localStorage.getItem('con_field3');
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like an answer, but rather like the idea of a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You should add all of your data to one object, stringify it, then add that to local storage under a single key.

When you load it, grab the one local storage item, parse it, then access the properties on the object.

e.g.

```
var save = function () {
    var data = {
        foo: 'bar'
    };

    localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
};

var load = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));

    var someProp = data.foo; // gives you 'bar'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main problem is that the fields are indexed beginning with 1, but your loop indexes from 0.

What about this?

```
var field = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
  field[i] = localStorage.getItem(window['con_field' + i]);
  document.purpose.field[i].value = window['con_field' + i]
}
```

Also, I'm not 100% on this, but I think using `document.getElementByID` is more cross-browser compatible than using bracket notation on the window object, but it's been a while since I wrote plain vanilla JS, so don't quote me.

Comment: I'd suggest to rename the form items, zero-based logic is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `document.purpose["field" + i].value = window['con_field' + i]`.